# What does BESTSOLFOUND mean in SCIP's callback?

Tags: callback, scip, pyscipopt

I would like to understand the meaning of `BESTSOLFOUND` in the `SCIP_EVENTTYPE_BESTSOLFOUND`. I have tried to write a callback to execute this event handler that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76594631/7414813). By referring to the related [document](https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/type__event_8h.php#aa7b9f5aece9817543b4ad6fcf51baf58) it mentioned that:

> a new best primal feasible solution was found

Now what I am willing to know is, what does it mean in the context of SCIP's B&B log file? And How can anyone find out when an event occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean how can you see in the logfile when a new incumbent is found? Whenever there is a new value in the `primalbound` column.

If you want to know whether your event handler works just print something in the exec callback.

Comment: Dear @Leon, thank you so much. I actually solved my issue based on your valuable comments in my previous question. Since I accepted your answer.